# Determining Memory Leak from Garbage Collection Log

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling

I am running my java file like this.

```
java -Xmx8m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:D:/MyExample/my.log MyJava
```

How do I interpret if there is memory leak in my program from the Garbage Collection log at my.log ?

Please do not suggest a tool to read my log. I want to know how to interpret the GC log to determine if there is a memory leak?

Comment: there isn't a real memory leak in pure Java (no native or JNI).

Answer (score 2):

What you can have in Java is an undesirable retension of memory.  This is not a memory leak in the strick sense but can still be a problem.

The simplest thing to do is to look at how much memory is used after a FULL GC.  This tells you the amount of memory retained.  If the amount retained continues to grow after you expect it to remain stable you have a "leak" Only you can determine at what point you expect it to be stable (not increasing or decreasing significantly)